# Emacsでハングルの入力をする時にキーバインドは変えずに入力する方法

Tags: emacs

OSXでEmacsを使っていてハングルの入力をOS標準のハングル入力のためのIMEに変更すると、`C-k`などのキーバインドも全てハングル入力に取られてしまい

```
﻿C-ㅛ is undefined
M-ㅍ is undefined
```

の様な事になってしまうのですが、日本語入力の時のようにキーバインドはそのままでハングルを入力するようにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS標準のIMEではなくEmacsの機能を使って変換をするのではだめですか?

M-x set-input-method RET　で例えばkorean-hangulを選ぶと、ControlやMetaの入力はそのままで、ハングル入力ができます。(ハングル/英字入力の切り替えは日本語入力の場合と同等です。私はC-\に割り当てていますがデフォルトで何だったか忘れてしまいました)

Comment: Emacsの機能で入力できたのですね。キーバインドを適当に割り当てて使ってみます。ありがとうございます。